# Using Cocoa Scripting Bridge to send email

Tags: objective-c, macos, email, cocoa

Using `Cocoa` Scripting Bridge to send email how can I add more then one attachment.

Here is my code:

```
MailApplication *mail = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Mail"];

emailMessageL = [[[mail classForScriptingClass:@"outgoing message"] alloc] initWithProperties:
NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [self.subjectField stringValue], @"subject", [self.messageContent stringValue], @"content", nil]];

[[mail outgoingMessages] addObject: emailMessageL];
emailMessageL.sender = [self.fromField stringValue];
emailMessageL.visible = YES;

if ( [mail lastError] != nil )
    return;

MailToRecipient *theRecipient = [[[mail classForScriptingClass:@"to recipient"] alloc] initWithProperties:
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [self.toField stringValue], @"address",
                                      nil]];
[emailMessageL.toRecipients addObject: theRecipient];

if ( [mail lastError] != nil )
    return;

NSString *attachmentFilePath = aStrUrl ;

if ( [attachmentFilePath length] > 0 )
{
    MailAttachment *theAttachment;
    theAttachment = [[[mail classForScriptingClass:@"attachment"] alloc] initWithProperties: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [[NSURL URLWithString:attachmentFilePath] path], @"fileName", nil]];

    [[emailMessageL.content attachments] addObject: theAttachment];

    if ( [mail lastError] != nil )
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll note you're adding a single object to `attachments`.  It's a mutable array you can add additional objects to.

For example, I created four text files in my `/tmp` directory on my development Macintosh and was able to do:

```
for(int index=1; index<4; index++)
    {
        NSString *attachmentFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"/private/tmp/%d.txt", index];

        if ( [attachmentFilePath length] > 0 )
        {
            MailAttachment *theAttachment;
            theAttachment = [[[mail classForScriptingClass:@"attachment"] alloc] initWithProperties: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [[NSURL URLWithString:attachmentFilePath] path], @"fileName", nil]];

            [emailMessageL.content.attachments addObject: theAttachment];

            if ( [mail lastError] != nil )
                return;
        }
    }
```

So in your case, simply `addObject:` an additional attachment and you'll be just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Problem completely solved.Grazie, Gianni.